# keep the _id of a record in the database

Tags: android, database, integer

I have a databse with three tables.

The first table is something like:

_id  user

The second table:

_id route user_id

and user_id is exactly the _id from the first table.

So when I insert in the first tabel a new record,I should keep the _id in order to insert it

in the second table.But how could I keep something that is autoincremented and given by the database?:-S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way, but you could grab (query for) the `_id` field right after you do your commit to the first table.  Then you will have the `user_id` for use in the second table.

Comment: as user might not be unique, there is no secure way to get the right _id with your solution

Comment: Hopefully there's a create date that could be sorted on which would allow the correct ID to be pulled.  The wording of the question suggests that we are only looking a small slice of the database.  That said, user names are usually unique.

Answer (score 4):

The `SQLiteDatabase` has an `insert()` method, which [returns the _id](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) you are looking for.